# rails avatar for user how to display avatar with user_helper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, carrierwave

I want to correctly display user avatar in some pages with size choose

```
module UsersHelper
    def avatar_for(user, options = { size: 50 })
        if user.nil? or user.avatar.nil?
            image_tag('/uploads/1.png', :size => 50)
        else
            image_tag(user.avatar.thumb, :size => 52)
        end
    end
end
```

and when I insert this code to the view `<%= avatar_for @user, size: 50 %>` rails don't display image
images uploading with carrierwave and edit with rmagick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you don't see an image because the method doesn't return an image tag. Yes it generates one but it doesn't return it. Instead it has a subsequent line about 'size = options[:size]' that causes Ruby to implicitly return the result of that operation.

Comment: Thanks, its work when user have avatar and doesnt work when user dont have avatar :(

Comment: Do you see an image at /uploads/1.png?

Comment: yep, i think problem in db, in column avatar, its not nil, its blank)))) i try if user.nil? || user.avatar.blank? and its work)

Comment: Maybe change avatar to be default